# How do you compile and run haskell on notepad++

Tags: haskell, notepad++, ghc

How do you compile and run Haskell on notepad++
I installed the plugin NppExec and then I pressed **F6**
I saved my Haskell file to `C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\haskell files\new 3.hs`

So on the command after I press **F6** I tried typing in a few different things:

```
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\haskell files\new 3.hs`
ghc.exe new 3.hs
haskell new
```

but I got these responses:

```
C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\haskell files\new 3.hs
CreateProcess() failed with error code 2:
The system cannot find the file specified.

ghc.exe new 3.hs
Process started >>>
target `new' is not a module name or a source file
<<< Process finished.

haskell new 3
CreateProcess() failed with error code 2:
The system cannot find the file specified.

================ READY ================
```

What is the correct way of compiling and executing at haskell file on notepad++?

Comment: Have you tried with a filename without spaces? It looks like that's the problem to me.

Comment: (In general ghc likes the module name to match the filename, and you can't have a module name with spaces.)

Comment: yes i have tried.. still errors

Comment: @user1988365 you have a space in your path to the file, "haskell files".  Try with a file that is in a path completely without spaces.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set NppExec to work in the current directory, so In Plugins, NppExec, tick `Follow $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)`.

Use the command `ghc new3.hs` when you press F6 (no spaces in filenames).

[image: Follow current directory]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Haskell with stack, I found a lovely way to run things quickly using NppExec. It's a simpler process than it looks and once you do it, you're good to go:

Suppose you have a file like this in a file called `yourFileName.hs`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Hello world!"
```

1. Press F6 to begin NppExec. (See Note 1 below.)
2. Paste the below into the window.

```
cd "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
stack ghci
// This is a comment you can delete. Note 2 below.
```

(See Note 3 below.)

3. Upon pressing the OK button, the Notepad++ console will run the Haskell interpreter.
4. Now, press F6 again. A warning menu will pop up.
5. Type this into the menu: `:cmd return $ unlines [":l yourFileName", ":main"]` and press ENTER. The file will execute. Pressing F6+ENTER will load and run the file again. When you open Notepad++ next time, this will still be there. Whenever you want to work with a new file, you will have to change `yourFileName` of course.

   Explanation: `:cmd return " . . . "` allows you to execute a string as multiple ghci commands, separated by `\n`. `unlines` takes a list of strings and joins them with `\n`. If you don't know about `$`, you'll learn it soon as it's part of basic Haskell.

   If you don't have a main function in your file, then instead use `:cmd return $ unlines [":l yourFileName"]`.

---

Note 1: For convenience, I used the `Settings > ShortCutMapper > Plugin Commands` to change Execute from F6 to F1.

Note 2: If you run multiple languages in this way (like maybe Lisp?), then you can replace the `// This is a comment...` line with `// :cmd return $ unlines [":l yourFileName", ":main"]` just so you have it for later when you switch back to Haskell.

Note 3: Instead of pasting `cd "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" stack ghci` into the NppExec window, a much simpler way to do all this is to paste `stack runghc "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` and nothing else needs to be done. However I found the console takes a lot longer to load and run the file in that case, so the method above is what I use.